# How do I select the activity to start?

Tags: android

I am working with android studio and combined three apps together. All the apps have been imported with their manifest file and each of those manifest files has an activity that is the main one that starts first. I have noticed that whichever application I import last, its main activity becomes the main activity of the whole project when its run. How do I change that?

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on the requirements of your application, you can define an Activity as "MainActivity" by defining the filter:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

This is an example:

```
   <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

But you can choose other `Activity` as `MainActivity` , for example my application starts with `SplashActivity` to load all neccesary resources and then finish and start my "MainActivity".

```
<activity android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You can keep other `Activity` as your `MainActivity`, probably an `Activity` that make transactions between `Fragments`, and you never finish it until you need to close completely the application.

Comment: This is true. However, when I combine the apps, they all come with there own intent filters.